# Overriding Rails as_json While Renaming Key and Customizing Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

How can I override the as_json method in Rails while using an alias for a nested association key and only including (or excluding) certain attributes in the JSON string?

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pages
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :pages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages, allow_destroy: true
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :paragraphs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs, allow_destroy: true
end

class Paragraph < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
  has_one :book, through: :page
end
```

I need to refer to the 'paragraphs' portion of the JSON as 'paragraphs_attributes' so Rails will accept them through strong params. And I'd like to limit the included attributes. I tried this syntax, but it's not working...

```
// on the Page model

def as_json(options = {})
  json = {:id => id, :name => name, :paragraphs_attributes => paragraphs(except: [:created_at, :updated_at])}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use the gem Active Model Serializers

- gem "active_model_serializers", in your Gemfile
- bundle install
- has_many :paragraphs, key: "paragraphs_attributes"

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md